# Is there a Regular Expression to find characters in sequence?

Tags: regex, string

I've searched high and low, and cannot seem to find anything, so finally deciding to beg for help here in the hopes anyone here can give me a hint!

My current task is to search a list of strings, for strings that contain characters in sequence. 
I'm struggling to find an efficient method, and thought maybe Regular Expressions might be able to pull it off?

So for example, I have the following data:

```
asdf1234qwer
asdfsdfgqwer
abcdefgh
zyxwv
123456789
hello world
```

Of those, ultimately, I only want "abcdefgh", "zyxwv" and "123456789" because the ENTIRE string contains characters in sequence. 
The first string I don't need, since only a part of it is in sequence (1234), not the entire string.

I haven't been able to find anything for regular expressions that seems like this is possible?

Comment: Maybe search harder :-) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15476488/how-to-identify-a-sequential-characters-using-regex

Comment: Yes it's possible, but it's kind of hard to tell you how to do it without knowing which language the regex is going to be written in.

Comment: @uSlackr: Thanks, I searched, that one never came up ...

Comment: @DrZoo  actually, eventually it's aimed for Oracle believe it or not :) I'm currently using a more complex method (of course) .. but was curious if RegEx could possibly be an option. The link by uSlackr seems to indicate "no, it's not easy - possible yes - but not easy" .. and I'm ok with that. It confirms what I thought - I just wanted to ensure I wasn't missing something else :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done but it isn't an "elegant" regex. Essentially you give regex a long list of patterns.  More in this [Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15476488/how-to-identify-a-sequential-characters-using-regex)

Comment: Thanks, I agree, it's as I figured, and understood ... I'll give this time just in case somebody comes up with some epiphany .. but I'll accept this answer in due time :)